# SpringToolSuite4 out of memory error, asking to exit workbench

Tags: spring-tool-suite, spring-tools-4

When I start SpringToolSuite4 it show error
[image]

and when I click to detail it show

[image]

I use Mac mini  M1 ( chip Apple M1, memory 8gb) and storage have 31.2 gb available.
Setting in contents/Eclipse/SpringToolSuite4.ini
[image]
And my project use tomcat v9.0
How I can fix error?

Comment: the error says something about not being able to create native threads, hard to tell what exactly is causing this. Does this happen every time you start STS right after starting it? Even with an empty workspace? You could also capture a thread dump (using jps to identify the process ID of the IDE, then jstack to capture the thread dump). Maybe that reveals more details here.